# Logging bus signals with timeseries - no measuring units

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm logging a bus signal with a `To Workspace` block set to `timeseries`. The bus definition contains a measuring unit but it does not propagate to the `timeseries` object. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

This occurs in `Matlab 2013a`.

Comment: I suspect it's not a bug or that you're doing anything wrong, just a feature that would be nice, but isn't implemented.  The Units of a bus or signal or parameter isn't used for anything in Simulation or Code Generation, purely for documentation.

Comment: I'll file a feature request.